# Want to find all results containing specific pattern in Azure Search explorer

Tags: azure

I want to find all records containing the pattern "170629-2" in Azure Search explorer, did try with

query string : customOfferId eq "170629-2*"

which only give one result back, which is the exactly match of "170629-2", but i do not get the records which have the patterns of "170629-20", "170629-21" or "170629-201".

Comment: Please show what you tried so community can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

1-You can't use standard analyzer as it will break your "words" in two parts:

e.g. 170629-20  will be breaked as 170629 and another entry as 20.

2-You can use regex and specify the pattern you want:

170629-2+.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_regex

PS: use &queryType=full to allow regex

Comment: Thanks for answer, tried your suggestion second part, but did have no success. Do you have the possibility to write the exactly query based on thing number 2, i will very much appreciate. Thanks

Comment: try escaping the "-" in the regex

Comment: Did solve it changing the standard analyzer to a Keyword Analyzer, that did the trick. Thanks :-)

Comment: awesome, mark as an answer if it was helpful to you